# 3rd Part solution for Huge file uploading

Tags: .net, iis, c#-4.0

I am looking for some third party solution to allow user to upload files of up to 10 GB (2 GB each file).

Please suggest some third party solutions which can be implemented with efficiency.

I am using .Net.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions about third party tools or other off-site resources are [generally off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you need reliable large file transfers I suggest to consider integration with [BitTorrent Sync API](https://getsync.com/api/) . Yes, it will not be pure .NET solution, but BitTorrent brings a lot to file transfer.

Without a bit more details about use case, I can not comment whether it is good fit with your solution in other aspects, but purely from file transfer it something worth looking at.